# SSIS: Excel source - is it possible to track changed made in excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

Lets say that I have the following columns in excel: Level, Group, Code, Name, date, Additional info with the following values:
1, A, 1234, John, 2019-09-01, info 1
1, A, 1234, John, 2019-09-01, info 2

I have currently the following logic for importing, if there is no record in database with certain code and level, then new record will be inserted, if code already exists in database then record will be updated. But as there is no unique identifier in excel then it is quit hard to update correct record. What are the common approaches in such cases?

Lets say that in above example, Group or date will be changed for one record. How to implement the logic, which updates correct record in db.

Comment: Please provide your code and what you have done to achieve this?

Comment: I gasped when I read this title. Just dump it into a staging table and do your work there. Don't use Excel as a database. It's bad for that.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to have a distinct dataset if there isn't a unique primary key. Without such a primary key you will not be able update only one row, but rather update one or more similar rows. In the current state, it is not possible to *accurately* track changes.

If you did have a unique primary key the simplest solution would be to append a datetime as a way to track changes and add it as a new row when any value changes. Your dataset would look like:

```
1, A, 1234, John, 2019-09-01, Info1, DateCreated, DateChanged
1, A, 1234, John, 2019-09-01, Info2, DateCreated, DateChanged2
1, A, 1234, John, 2019-09-01, Info3, DateCreated, DateChanged3
```

It is important to remember that this only works with a static primary key, certain fields that are commonly used for composite keys may not work. Users could change their name or rectify an incorrectly entered birth date which could change some composite keys.

In SSIS this would be implemented using two Lookup tasks:

- In the first Lookup Task compare the primary key. If the primary key does not exist, use a Derived Column task to set the DateCreated and DateModified to GETDATE().
- If the primary key does exist, run a second lookup task that compares all rows in the record. If they are all identical it means that there were no changes to the record and no update needs to be sent to the database.
- If there is a difference then use a Derived Column SSIS task to only update the DateModified column to GETDATE() and add it as a new row.

These three branching options should account for every potential state: New record, existing record with no changes, existing record with changes

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a unique identifier then you should try to create your own. In a similar case I will use a derived column to concatenate all values that I am sure it will not changes. As Example:

```
Level + "|" + Code + "|" + Name + "|" + Additional info
```

Then I will compare the source data and the existing data based on that derived column. You can choose to store these derived column in the destination database or you can use a staging table to store these values.